# How do I remove NULL values from a dynamic pivot output

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm running into an issue where the output for my dynamic pivot contains thousands of NULL values that I would like to replace with 0. I am not able to use ISNULL before the pivot is generated because there aren't any NULL values in the original table. I've searched everywhere and I havn't located anything that works for me. Here is my code.

```
DECLARE @col NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @col =  (SELECT STRING_AGG(CONVERT(NVARCHAR(MAX),CONCAT('[',[order_date],']')),',') FROM
            (
            SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10000 (CAST(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,[purchase-date],127) AS DATE)) AS order_date
            FROM dbo.Amazon_FBAFulfilledShipments_Report
            ORDER BY order_date ASC
            ) trial_table);
SELECT @col
PRINT @col
SET @sql = 
'SELECT ship_country,sku,' + @col + '
FROM
(
SELECT [ship-country] AS ship_country,sku,CAST([quantity-shipped] as INT) AS quantity_shipped,CAST(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,[purchase-date],127) AS DATE) AS order_date
FROM dbo.Amazon_FBAFulfilledShipments_Report
) as Source_table
PIVOT
(SUM(quantity_shipped) FOR order_date IN (' + @col +')
)AS pivot_table'

PRINT @sql
EXECUTE (@sql)
```

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72639331/use-sum-function-inside-a-pivot-table

Comment: @DaleK I don't believe it does because I'm dealing with a dynamic pivot output. In the link you gave, the table has set column names, whereas mine does not

Comment: You can still build a similar query, just dynamically. Looks very doable, but an actual example of your end query, and min/max numbers of columns would help clarify.

Comment: An example of my end query? As in a picture of my result? The min/max numbers of columns is 1000 (or roughly three years worth of days as column headers). Each item (sku) has an order quantity for different days, but obviously not all days. This is why there are NULL values

Comment: No pictures please :) but having an idea of the range of values of `@col` - but why not just change your your `@col` query to produce a bunch of case expressions?

Comment: 1000 columns? Something makes me thing there is a design flaw there...

Comment: @DaleK Hm. Well I'm not super familiar with SQL (just started job) so I haven't used CASE yet. If you're able, could you briefly explain how I would apply CASE to a dynamic pivot?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72621391/61305

Comment: @DaleK Oh, it's definitely a design flaw. My boss wants me to generate a report so that he can load the data into Excel and do some forecasting. His requirement is that each day be a column. That's why I have to do this.

Comment: @AceCharm101 the answer I linked to shows you how to use a case expression? But Aarons goes one further and shows a dynamic pivot.

Comment: @DaleK Okay, I will look into Aaron's response and try to apply it to my issue. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Just think about it this way: you need two different sets of columns to jam into the dynamic SQL: one for the pivot (`FOR col IN ([day1], [day2], etc.)`) and one for the output (`day1 = COALESCE(day1, 0), day2 = COALESCE(day2, 0), etc.`. [This may also be useful](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand).

Comment: @AaronBertrand Ahhh. I see what you're saying. I might reach out to you tomorrow after I've given it a good effort and have some progress to show. Is that okay with you?

Comment: Also `DISTINCT TOP 10000 ` why? Please make it make sense

Comment: @AaronBertrand lol. So in the original table, the [purchase-date] column has NVARCHAR values like yyyy-mm-ddTHH-mm-ss-z. Since I want to only have "day" column headers (such as 2022-06-10) and no repeats: this is why I have the DISTINCT. The TOP 10000 is honestly just because I want current data, and I havn't been able to use an ORDER BY ASC to get recent days. When I had DISTINCT TOP 1000 ........ ORDER BY...... ASC     I only got from 2018 to 2020

Comment: Ok, but you're ultimately grouping by just the date right?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I edited the above comment, but if you need further clarification let me know.

Answer (score 2):

The key is to think about it this way: you need two different sets of columns to jam into the dynamic SQL: one for the pivot (`FOR col IN ([day1], [day2], ...)`) and one for the output (`day1 = COALESCE(day1, 0), day2 = COALESCE(day2, 0), ...`). [This previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72621391/61305) and [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2783/script-to-create-dynamic-pivot-queries-in-sql-server/?utm_source=AaronBertrand) may be useful.

Here's a working script (and [here's an example db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=40c84da3d531792b9bf8aa3b14d5214f)).

```
DECLARE @OutputCols nvarchar(max),
        @PivotCols  nvarchar(max),
        @sql        nvarchar(max),
        @StartingDate date = '20180101';

;WITH src(d) AS
(
  SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(max), QUOTENAME(CONVERT(date, [purchase-date])), 120)
    FROM dbo.Amazon_FBAFulfilledShipments_Report
    WHERE [purchase-date] >= @StartingDate
    GROUP BY CONVERT(date, [purchase-date])
)
SELECT @PivotCols  = STRING_AGG(d, ','),
       @OutputCols = STRING_AGG(CONCAT(d, ' = COALESCE(', d, ', 0)'), ',')
FROM src;

SET @sql = N'SELECT ship_country,sku,' + @OutputCols + '
FROM
(
  SELECT [ship-country] AS ship_country,sku,
    CAST([quantity-shipped] as INT) AS quantity_shipped,
    CAST(CONVERT(datetimeoffset,[purchase-date],127) AS DATE) AS order_date
  FROM dbo.Amazon_FBAFulfilledShipments_Report
  WHERE [purchase-date] >= @StartingDate
) AS Source_table 
PIVOT
(
  SUM(quantity_shipped) FOR order_date IN (' + @PivotCols +')
) AS pivot_table'

PRINT @sql;
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @sql, N'@StartingDate date', @StartingDate;
```

Multiple things:

- I got rid of the `DISTINCT TOP 10000`. If you want "current" data, just use a `WHERE` clause (which will produce more predictable results, like since Jan 2018, not since 10,000 distinct purchase date values ago), and use it in *both* queries (there's no sense limiting your PIVOT list to 10,000 dates if your dynamic query queries ALL OF TIME, though I'm not sure how you'd consume such a query anyway).
- Use `QUOTENAME()`; it is much safer and less tedious than trying to use string concatenation to add your own `[` and `]`. Dynamic SQL probably isn't on the radar in this specific scenario, but it is not a good practice and sets a bad example.
- Don't use `EXECUTE()`, always use `sys.sp_executesql`.
- [Dynamic SQL advice here](https://sqlblog.org/dynamic-sql).

Comment: @AaronBertrand This is phenomenal. Thank you so much for the query/ links, this is much closer to what my boss wants so you're directly helping my job security haha. I really appreciate it.